# Check if view within other view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I’m using **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to move UIImageView. Now i’m need to check if user moved my object within other vectored-PDF UIImageView.

For example we have red bar that we are moving and we need to move red bar inside blue bar (blue bar is vector PDF). How can we check that?

Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pVZA.png

Example code:

```
@IBAction func moveRedBox(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x,
                                      y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        // Here we will check that redBox inside blueBox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if two view's overlap you can use the [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) function.

**Update:** Just found out that there is also an intersects method on CGRect in Swift

```
let doRectsIntersect = rect1.intersects(rect2)
```

Comment: It’s really good function, but it works only for rectangles. If it’s any way to do same check for vector images?

Comment: Hmm, not sure detecting the intersection of vector images.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. This helped me:

```
if view1.frame.contains(view2.center) {
    // do your thing
  }
```

Full example:

```
@IBAction func moveRedBox(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

  ...

  switch recognizer.state {

  case .Ended:

    if blueBox.frame.contains(recognizer.view!.center) {
      print("Yep")
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check position of UIImageView

```
image.frame.origin.x >= view.frame.origin.x
image.frame.origin.y >= view.frame.origin.y
```

put this code when the movement done

Comment: This doesn't account for the `image` view being far to the bottom-right of `view`.